# NODEJS unable to send json formatted response?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send  json response from my nodejs application to the client. However, the response does not seem to be in the right format can someone point me what is it that i am doing wrong ?

Below is subset of my code

```
var insertdata = "create-fail";
var updatedata = "update-fail";
var deletedata = "delete-fail";

insertdata = "{ create:pass ,";
updatedata = "update:pass ,";
deletedata = "delete:pass }";

var jsondata = insertdata+updatedata+deletedata;
res.send(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
```

Output browser:

"{ create:pass ,update:pass ,delete:pass }"

Comment: `jsondata` is a string. The output is a string. Nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.stringify should receive an object, not a string.

```
var jsondata = {'create':'pass', 'update':'pass', 'delete':'pass'};
res.send(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an object:

```
object = { hello: 1 }
```

This is a string:

```
string = "{ 'hello': 1 }"
```

The string looks similar to the object, because its format is JSON (Javascript Object Notation), which is inspired in the way `object` is declared above.

Objects can't travel across the internet, but strings can. You can go from object to string using `JSON.stringify()`:

```
string = JSON.stringify(object)
```

When you receive it on the other side, go back using `JSON.parse()`:

```
object = JSON.parse(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsondata` is a string - and then you're stingifying it. If you're using jQuery, use `$.parseJSON` or use the json2 library.